# How to include link to app in Facebook Post?

Tags: ios, facebook, app-store

I have an IOS app that posts a link to facebook.

Is it possible to have that link point to the app store?

So basically I have a player playing my game, they post their highscore. Their friend sees this post on their friends wall, the click it, takes them to download the app.

The trouble is, how can I get the link to point to the app store if the app isn't published and has no ID when I'm coding the actual app?

Answer (score 0):

Then finish app and publish it, and after that update the link.

Comment: So for 2 weeks the link does nothing while I wait for the changes to get approved? I'm trying to see if there's a better solution.

Comment: I don't think there is another solution. But still you can app post high score, but without redirecting to app store.

Answer (score 0):

Before uploading the app, obviously you will add it to the iTunesconnect.
In iTunesConnect, you will get the app ID for your app when you will add it.

Use the following format to link it to your app :

http://itunes.apple.com/app/id[app_apple_id]

[app_apple_id] : Replace this (along with square brackets) with the app ID, that you will get after adding the app to iTunesConnect.